# cesium javascript czml library

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

I'm trying to adapt a CZML example for my purpose. I start running it on my local machine after changing all the requirements but it is not running.

Only part of it is running, for example when I'm using czml for a label then it is running. Here is the code of that

```js
{
    "id":"/Application/STK/Scenario/simple/Facility/AGI",
    "label":{
        "fillColor":{
            "rgba":[
                0,255,255,255
            ]
        },
        "font":"10pt Lucida Console",
        "horizontalOrigin":"LEFT",
        "outlineColor":{
            "rgba":[
                0,0,0,255
            ]
        },
        "pixelOffset":{
            "cartesian2":[
                12.0,0.0
            ]
        },
        "scale":1.0,
        "show":true,
        "style":"FILL",
        "text":"AGI",
        "verticalOrigin":"CENTER"
    },
    "position":{
        "cartesian":[
            1216469.9357990976,-4736121.71856379,4081386.8856866374
        ]
    }
}
```

But I also want to show an image at the same place, then it is not running and also not giving any error code. Here is the code for that:

```js
{
    "id":"Headquarters",
    "availability" : "2013-11-08T09:00:00Z/2013-11-09T17:04:54.9962195740191Z",
    "billboard":{
        "color":{
            "rgba":[
                0,255,255,255
            ]
        },
        "horizontalOrigin":"LEFT",
        "image":"localhost//Cesium-b19/Apps/Sandcastle/images/DownArrow.png",
        "scale":1.0,
        "show":true,
        "verticalOrigin":"CENTER"
    }, 
    "position":{
        "epoch" : "2013-11-08T09:00:00Z",
        "cartesian":[
            1216469.9357990976,-4736121.71856379,4081386.8856866374
        ]
    }
}
```

What is happening with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are using for the "image" property is not correct.  It's being interpreted as a relative URL because you are missing the "http://" prefix.

The image displays correctly after replacing the "image" property with:

```
"image":"http://cesiumjs.org/images/Cesium_Logo.png",
```